# Custom html tab implementation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my use case : create tab like experience. clicking on add button creates a

(horz tab button) and a corresponding div, which is linked via `onclick listener`, dynamically.

problems :

1. on clicking add button, values from previous tabs are reset (which is obvious wrt to the way `$tabs_prev` & `$menu_prev` is populated) and
2. their respective `js` goes away (which I can't understand, why?)
3. a remove tab implementation (because the way I've coded these tabs, removing a tab and corresponding div isn't really simple, so, any clues in this direction, maybe?)

code : fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g58fzs75/1/

HTML:

```
<body>
        <input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="1"></input>

        <div id="template_tabBtn" style="display:none">
            <input type="button" value="add" onclick="addTab()"></input>
        </div>

        <ul id="menu">
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs">
        </div>

        <div id="template_tabBar" style="display:none">
            <li>
                <input type="button" id="tab_btn" class="template_tabBar" value="Tab" onclick="tabClick(this)"></input>
            </li>
        </div>

        <div id="template_tabs" style="display:none">
            <div id="tabs" class="template_tabs tab_div" value="1">
                <input type="text" id="txt" class="template_tabs" value="alert"></input>
                <input type="button" id="btn" class="template_tabs" value="alert"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
    <style>
        ul#menu {
            padding: 0;
        }
        ul#menu li {
            display: inline;
        }
        ul#menu li input {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
        }
        ul#menu li input:hover {
            background-color: orange;
        }
    </style>
```

jQuery :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $tabs_prev = "";
            $menu_prev = "";
            $add_btn = "";
            $current_tabID = "";

            function tabClick(id) {
                showCurrent($(id).attr('id'));
            }

            function addTab() {
                var tabCount = parseInt($('#hidden').val()) + 1;
                $('#hidden').val(tabCount);
                run(tabCount);
                showCurrent($('#tabs-' + tabCount).attr('id'));
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $add_btn = "<li>" + $('#template_tabBtn').html() + "</li>";
                run(1);
            });

            function run(tabCount) {
                //$tabs_prev += main($('#template_tabs'),tabCount);//alert("tabs\n"+$tabs_prev);
                $menu_prev += main($('#template_tabBar'), tabCount); //alert("menu\n"+$menu_prev);

                $('#tabs').html($('#tabs').html() + main($('#template_tabs'), tabCount));
                $('#menu').html($menu_prev + $add_btn);
                logic(tabCount);
            }

            function main(target, tabCount) {
                $htmlBackup = $(target).html();
                $('.' + $(target).attr('id')).each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + "-" + tabCount).removeClass($(target).attr('id'));
                    $(this).attr('value', $(this).attr('value') + "-" + tabCount);
                });
                $html = $(target).html();
                $(target).html($htmlBackup);
                return $html;
            }

            function logic(tabCount) {
                $('#btn-' + tabCount).click(function() {
                    alert($('#txt-' + tabCount).val());
                });
            }

            function showCurrent(current_id) {
                $('.tab_div').each(function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var id_num = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, id.length);
                    var current_id_num = current_id.substr(current_id.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, current_id.length);
                    if (id_num == current_id_num) {
                        $("#tabs-" + id_num).show();
                        $('#tab_btn-' + id_num).css({
                            "background-color": "orange"
                        });
                    } else {
                        $("#tabs-" + id_num).hide();
                        $('#tab_btn-' + id_num).css({
                            "background-color": "black"
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: pls refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g58fzs75/1/) for ease of use.

Comment: just, fyi : I coded this another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ha31qxoj/1/) wherein I used easyui.js but my use case is to preferably not to use external tab libraries.

Comment: You have to HTML-elements with the `id` `tabs`. Ids need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your javascript is disappearing is because resetting the `innerHTML` deletes the `onclick` handlers on the elements. Why: the original elements are destroyed, including references to events and new elements are created.

The code responsible for this:

```
 $('#tabs').html($('#tabs').html() + main($('#template_tabs'), tabCount));
```

Please use jQuery's appending of an element by cloning the template tab:

```
 $('#tabs').append($('#template_tabs').clone(true));
```

- `Append` appends `htmlstrings` or `element`s to an parent element. It's a buffed up version of the documents native 'appendChild'.
- `clone` clone the template element (makes a copy). You can do this in your function `main` and return it to the `append` function.

```js
 function main(tabCount)
 {
     var node = $('#template_tabs').clone(true));
     //do things with the node, like setting an onclick handler, or id.
     //example
     node.setAttribute("id", "tab" + tabCount);
 }
```

Removing can be done also:

```
function removeNode(node)
{
    //provide a node via jQuery
    //example: removeNode($("#tab2")) <-- now tab2 will be removed from the DOM.
    node.remove();
}
```